# linq to sql multiple Where() statements not creating a single expression

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, expression, linq-expressions

My understanding is that the following code:

```
IQueryable<Things> things = dataContext.Things.Take(10);
if (fromDate > new DateTime(1980, 1, 1))
    things = things.Where(a => a.InsertedDate > fromDate);
if (toDate < defaultDate)
    things = things.Where(a => a.InsertedDate < toDate);
```

should result in a query (assuming the dates pass the conditionals) like:

```
select top 10 [fields] from things
where inserteddate > '1/8/2010'
    and inserteddate < '1/12/2010'
```

I've stepped through and confirmed that the two Where() statements are getting set, but when I call things.ToList(), I get the query:

```
select top 10 [fields] from things
```

Why aren't the two where's getting incorporated into the actual query getting run?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is wrong. The call to [`Queryable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) should be at the *end* to get the query you want:

```
IQueryable<Things> things = dataContext.Things;

if (fromDate > new DateTime(1980, 1, 1))
{
    things = things.Where(a => a.InsertedDate > fromDate);
}

if (toDate < defaultDate)
{
    things = things.Where(a => a.InsertedDate < toDate);
}

things = things.Take(10);
```

When you call `Take` first it finds the top ten elements from the entire database and then evaluates the Where cause for these 10 items only. The result would typically contain less than ten elements.

Your incorrect code could in theory be run as a single database query:

```
SELECT [fields]
FROM
(
   SELECT TOP 10 [fields] FROM table1
) T1
WHERE inserteddate > '2010-01-08'
AND inserteddate < '2010-01-12'
```

It seems that this optimization has not been implemented. But I doubt that a query like this it is used very often.

Comment: Moving the Take to the end does not change anything except removing the top 10 from the query.  I still don't get the where clause when the query is run.  So you just can't chain where's like this?

Answer (score 2):

Even though my example was instantiating the var as IQueryable, my actual code was doing so as IEnumerable.  IEnumerable handles Where() differently apparently such that only the first expression will get executed against the DB and all subsequent ones do so in memory unlike IQueryable.  I blame extension methods.

Comment: +1 for figuring it out yourself. Yes it does make a difference if you use `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`. I don't really think it's a problem with extension methods though - it's a fundamental difference between the way the two types work.